# FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: python, directory, path

I have a main "MAIN" folder and I would like to create several sub-folders within this called "test_1", "test_2", and so on. I have done the following which successfully creates the "MAIN" folder and "test_1" within the main folder; however, it fails to create the subsequent sub-folders. It raises the following error:

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'MAIN\\test_1'
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in my logic and thus, my code. I would really appreciate any assistance on this.

Here's the relevant snippet of my code:

```
        self.counter = 1
        self.MAIN_folder = "MAIN"
        if not os.path.exists(self.MAIN_folder):
            os.makedirs(self.MAIN_folder)

        self.test_folder = os.path.join(self.MAIN_folder, "test")

        if not os.path.exists(self.test_folder):
            os.makedirs(self.test_folder + "_" + str(self.counter))
        else:
            self.counter += 1
            os.makedirs(self.test_folder + "_" + str(self.counter))
```

Comment: That error message is pretty straightforward. Maybe research [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) and check if it might accept an argument that can help?

Comment: Also, you use `os.path.exists` but not with the same argument as `os.makedirs` so I'm not exactly sure what you expected to happen

Comment: @DeepSpace  I wouldn't ask this question if I could figure out the error that easily. Yes, I do understand that test_1 exists but I wasn't sure where I was going wrong in my logic that was causing that error since I do have a check implemented to see if self.test_folder exists. Due to Allie's explanation now, I get where I went wrong in my check.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not checking whether or not the relevant folder exists first. You only check `self.test_folder` which is never a folder that you create, thus your program continually attempts to create the `MAIN/test_1`.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to find out - i.e. where I was going wrong in my logic.